# How to render a GraphViz Dot file via holoviz and NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz, server-side-rendering, holoviews

So I look onto [docs](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/NetworkX.html)  and see that they use Graphviz, yet do not use any files... And I have a [4mil+ .dot (70mb) graph file](https://github.com/OlegJakushkin/ServicesPetriNet/releases/download/0.1.0/figure.dot) I want to render. How to open and render GraphViz Dot file via holoviz and NetworkX?

##Update:
Tested @GijsWobben sample: shows nada on even [small 6kb file](https://github.com/OlegJakushkin/ServicesPetriNet/releases/download/0.1.0/figure6.dot)
[image]

Something similar was expected for the small file:
[image]

Comment: I would guess you'd read the file using something from https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html and then follow the docs you linked once you've got your graph as a NetworkX object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
import hvplot.networkx as hvnx

import networkx as nx
import holoviews as hv

# Read the file
G = nx.drawing.nx_agraph.read_dot("./figure.dot")

# Rest of the tutorial...
spring = hvnx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

# Show the plot
spring
```

Comment: Dear Gijs: Seems to not draw anything at all silently, updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: The example says "rest of tutorial ...". This code assigns a plot to `spring`. To show the plot you'll have to state the `spring` variable at the end of a cell (just like in the tutorial)

Comment: Fine, I've updated my answer. But something not showing in Jupiter or whatever environment you are using is not related to the code.