# How to convert a NetworkX graph into cuGraph?

Tags: python, graph, cuda, gpu, rapids

So I load a [dot file graph using NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65354596/1973207). I want to perform operations on GPU on top of it in cuGraph. How to convert NetworkX graph into cuGraph?

Answer (score 3):

You can call networkx graph objects directly into cugraph.  This medium post covers it: https://medium.com/rapids-ai/rapids-cugraph-networkx-compatibility-d119e417557c